I got error using dependency injection in Livewire component
On a Laravel/Livewire site I try to use dependency injection for defining service class for key/values writing reading.
I defined 2 classes, app/Library/Services/Interfaces/KeyDataInterface.php :
<?php

namespace App\Library\Services\Interfaces;

use App\Models\KeyData;

/**
 * Write/read key value into/from storage
 */
interface KeyDataInterface
{

    /**
     * Write key/value into storage
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @param string $value
     * @param int $durationInSeconds
     *
     * @return KeyData - created model
     */
    public static function write( string $key, string $value, int $durationInSeconds = 60 ): KeyData;
}

and implementation in app/Library/Services/KeyDataInDbService.php:
<?php

namespace App\Library\Services;

use App\Library\Services\Interfaces\KeyDataInterface;

use App\Models\KeyData;
use Carbon\Carbon;

/**
 * Write/read key value into/from db
 *
 */
readonly class KeyDataInDbService implements KeyDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Write key/value into db
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @param string $value
     * @param int $durationInSeconds
     *
     * @return KeyData - created model
     */
    public static function write( string $key, string $value, int $durationInSeconds = 60 ): KeyData {
        $keyData = KeyData::getByKey($key)->getByValue($value)->first();
//        scopeGetByValue
        if(!empty($keyData)) {
            $keyData->expired_at = Carbon::now('UTC')
                ->addSeconds($durationInSeconds);
            return $keyData;
        }

        return KeyData::create([
            'key' => $key,
            'value' => $value,
            'expired_at' => Carbon::now('UTC')->addSeconds($durationInSeconds)
        ]);
    }

}

I tied them in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php :
public function register(): void
{
    $this->app->bind(
        'App\Library\Services\Interfaces\KeyDataInterface',
        'App\Library\Services\KeyDataInDbService'
    );
}

But when I tried to use is in Livewire component :
class TheTaskIsViewed extends Component
{
    ...
    public KeyDataInterface $keyDataService;

    public function boot(KeyDataInterface $keyDataService)
    {
        $this->keyDataService = $keyDataService;
    }


    public function mount(int $taskId)
    {

I got error:
Property type not supported in Livewire for property: [{}]

In browser I see pointing to 12 line of a file which has only 8 lines:

Component TheTaskIsViewed is used on resources/views/livewire/test.blade.php as :
<div class="admin_page_container" id="app_image_admin_page_container pt-64" x-cloak>
    <fieldset class="p-1 m-1 mb-6 bordered">
        <legend class="bordered">
            the-task-is-viewed
        </legend>
        <livewire:admin.the-task-is-viewed taskId="5"/>
    </fieldset>
</div>

Why have I got this error and how it can be fixed ?
"laravel/framework": "^10.48.4",
"livewire/livewire": "^3.4.9",


In Livewire's public properties, Only some types are supported.
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/properties#supported-property-types
If you don't use $keyDataService in the view, make it private or protected.
protected KeyDataInterface $keyDataService;

If you want to use $keyDataService in views, create a custom type.
